# Send a json request in Volley

Tags: android, json, request, android-volley

I am having problems sending a particular json request using `Volley` on `Android`.

I am using the following for sending simple json requests:

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("userId", "testUserId");
    jsonObject.put("password", "testPass");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("JSONexception","JSON EXCEPITON: "+e.tostring());
}
```

But for more complex request, I am not sure how to create the json body request. Here it is an example of the json request I would like to create:

```
{
“userId” : “testUserId”,
“password” : “testPass”,
“validParameters” : [
    {
        “key” : “testKey”,
        “value” : “testValue”
    }
],
“requestTimestamp” : null
}
```

Comment: you need learn some JSON basics ... you need add JSONArray with name "validParameters" and then add new JSONObject to this array with "key" and "value" properties ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
final JSONArray  jsonArray =new JSONArray();
final JSONObject newjsonObject =new JSONObject();  
try {
jsonObject.put("userId", "testUserId");
jsonObject.put("password", "testPass");
jsonObject.put("validParameters",jsonArray );
jsonArray.put(newjsonObject); 
newjsonObject.put("key","testKey"); 
newjsonObject.put("value","testValue"); 

} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.d("JSONexception","JSON EXCEPITON: "+e.tostring());
}
```

Try this

Comment: thanks for the support, it works as expected for the json example i gave, and now I can use it with any other json configuration.

Comment: actually there is no specific structure for json and it differs in different case. The above case  is an example for a jsonArray inside a jsonObject, similarly there can jsonObject inside jsonArray cases as well. So you will need to design the post body as required by the structure. It will be better if you tryout some examples to make sense of this